# How to get elements from List A that don't exist in List B

Tags: java, lambda, filter, java-8, java-stream

I'd like to filter all objects from List A that don't exist in List B. How to do that using Java Stream?

```
List<MyClass> A
List<MyClass> B
```

I'd like to filter by MyClass.id field

My attempts:

```
List<MyClass> actionsToRemoval = A.stream()
                .filter(oldAction -> B.stream()
                        .noneMatch(action -> action.getId() != null && action.getId().equals(oldAction.getId()))).collect(
                        Collectors.toList());
```

But the result is opposite to my expectations

**UPDATE:**

My code from DEV:

Data from DB:

```
private void removeUnnecessaryCorrectiveActions(List<IncidentCorrectiveActionDto> correctiveActionsDto) 
{
//correctiveActionsDto - data from Frontend, for exampe that object contains 3 objects with id=1 (this object should be updated), id=2 (new object), id=3 (ne w object)
List<IncidentCorrectiveAction> oldActions = incidentCorrectiveActionRepository
                .findByIncidentId(id)
//oldActions -> for example one object with id=1, fetched from database

    List<IncidentCorrectiveAction> actionsToRemoval = oldActions.stream()
                    .filter(oldAction -> correctiveActionsDto.stream()
                            .noneMatch(action -> action.getId() != null && action.getId().equals(oldAction.getId()))).collect(
                            Collectors.toList());
```

So in this case my List actionsToRemoval should return 0 elements as we ant to add 2 new elements and save them in database.

Another case:
oldActions -> 3 objects with id=1, id=2, id=3

correctiveActionsDto (object from frontend) -> contains 1 object with id=1

IN this case actionsToRemoval List should return 2 elements: with id= 2 and id = 3 as these objects should be removed from database.

Comment: I can not reproduce your issue. Your code works for me. Can you please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the content of both lists, so we can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
List<MyClass> FilteredOutput =
              A.stream()
              .filter(e -> B.stream().map(MyClass::getid).anyMatch(id -> 
              id.equals(e.getid())))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Take List `A` as stream and then Taking ID from `A` compare with `B`'s ID.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to encapsulate the predicate logic in your object's equals method, then use `B.contains(x)` as a filter.
Something like:

```java
class MyClass{
   private Integer id;
   ...
   public boolean equals(Object other){
     return other instanceof MyClass && other.getId() != null && other.getId().equals(this.id);
}
```

Then:

```java
List<MyClass> A = ...;
List<MyClass> B = ...;

List<MyClass> diffAB = A.stream().filter(v -> !B.contains(v)).collect(Collectors.asList());
```